# Excel Grouping (or using SQL)

Tags: vba, excel

Believe I am overthinking this.  So created a SQL report to generate data that looks like this:

```
Client# Parent# Industry    Client Name A   B   C   D   E   F   G   
1       0       Agriculture ABC Co.     0   0   0   50  0   0   0   
2       1       Agriculture DEF Co.     25  0   0   0   0   0   0   
3       2       Agriculture GHI Co.     0   0   0   0   0   0   75
```

There are like 10,000 rows.  If you noticed, there is a client number and a parent number.  The 3 results displayed above are sub companies that are all under the "ABC Co." business.  What is the best way to group them all together into one line within an Excel report?  Have the result look like this:

```
Client# Parent# Industry    Client Name A   B   C   D   E   F   G   Total
1       0       Agriculture ABC Co.     25  0   0   50  0   0   75  150
```

Was thinking possibilities being:

1) Customize SQL code to format the data to look the way I want it (would be nice bc every time I run the report, I would have to do minimal work after it collects the data).  I understand though it is more appropriate to use SQL just to retreive the data.

2) There being an option within Excel to accomplish this.

3) Create a macro to sort through the data and format it the way I want.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Is there a limit to how far the sub-clients can be nested (your example shows 3, can it be 5 or 50?)   " I understand though it is more appropriate to use SQL just to retreive the data." - it is correct that SQL shouldn't be used to 'display' the data...I'd consider grouping part of retrieving here.

Comment: Technically no limit but the parent companies can be like 3-4 deep.  Feel that grouping within Excel is the ideal path to go as well if possible.

Comment: parent id = 0 means it's the top record (I guess the parent record)?

Comment: Yes if parent id is 0, that is the top/parent record.

Comment: kinda funny that a group of VBA / Excel posters put the question on hold for being too broad, yet through SQL eyes, this isn't too broad at all.

Comment: @twelfth It's not tagged as SQL, though...

Comment: @CindyMeister I removed the SQL tags as they said it was too broad.  Was seeing if anyone had an Excel answer but just closed this question out as it was still marked as too broad after removing the tags.  Twelfth got me the answer

Comment: look closely: your "should be" result is probably wrong. either omit the "Client  name" from the result, or make it 2 lines: ABC Co- 50; DEF Co - 25 (can't explain it more verbosely here)

Comment: Yes, Mark, I can see the problem. There is a vote to re-open, but as your question stands I can't in good conscience support that. If you'll edit (and give me a "ping") to remove all but the first question, change the title (only SQL, not Excel), add some of your original SQL (the stuff @twelfth was missing in order to answer in a simple manner) and adjust the tags again I think we can get this re-opened...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

" So created a SQL report to generate data that looks like this:"

The reason for your downvotes is likely due to you not posting the SQL code here.  Leaves me guessing at your table formats, so for my ease... select * from mytable is what I'll guess you've used.  I'm left guessing column names too...in future questions, more information is helpful so I assume less.

```
select t1.client, t2.client, t3.client, t4.client, t1.parent, t2.parent, t3.parent, t1.*
from maytable t1
left join mytable t2 on t1.parent = t2.client
left join mytable t3 on t2.parent = t3.client
left join mytable t4 on t3.parent = t4.client
etc pending how deep this relation goes.
```

This will give you a list showing the parents.  The t1.* is simply to grab the data columns related, you should write out your columns in full, I'm being lazy since no column list was supplied.  The client IDs should look like this in your example (I've ignored parentID in my list below)

```
row 1 - 1 , 0, null , null
row 2 - 2 , 1 , 0, null
row 3 - 3 , 2 , 1, 0
```

Now we need a case statement...when the parent = 0 then show that client id.

```
select client_id, case when t1.parentid = 0 then t1.client_id
                      when t2.parentid = 0 then t2.client_id
                      when t3.parentid = 0 then t3.client_id
                      when t4.parentid = 0 then t4.clientID
                  end as parent_ID
      , t1.*
from (same as above query)
```

You can take what was just written above and call it a sub query and select from it, this time grabbing the sums of the columns you want.

```
select parent_id, sum(a), sum(b), etc...
from   
  (select client_id, case when t1.parentid = 0 then t1.client_id
                      when t2.parentid = 0 then t2.client_id
                      when t3.parentid = 0 then t3.client_id
                      when t4.parentid = 0 then t4.clientID
                  end as parent_ID
      , t1.*
       from maytable t1
left join mytable t2 on t1.parent = t2.client
left join mytable t3 on t2.parent = t3.client
left join mytable t4 on t3.parent = t4.client
etc pending how deep this relation goes. ) a
group by parent_id
```

Unfortunately this is the best code I can provide with the limited info you've given.

Comment: This is perfect.  Was looking for general advice and using a case statement is exactly what I should have thought of for the SQL approach!  Thank you again.